# Suggestion for Multi-points slider for angular

Tags: angular

I can't find a slider that works with angular that can have more than 2 points.
I found the ng5-slider library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng5-slider) that works perfectly for a minValue and maxValue but what I'm trying to acheive is this: [image]

a slider that holds time data (24 hours) and shows events based on the time on it.
Any suggestions please?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't found any slider that can handle multi points but I found a better slider that is compatible with Angular:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-slider/ngx-slider